# I'm making a SQL-backed website for an annual conference event. How should I structure edges between objects?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have the following models, each cataloged in its own SQL table:

```
Person (id, lastname, firstname, description, ...)
Event (id, name)
Timeslot (id, time_start, time_end)
Session (id, name, description, location)
```

An Event contains multiple Timeslots, a Timeslot contains one or more Sessions, and a Session contains one or more Persons (the same Person can appear in multiple Sessions, and the same Session may span multiple Timeslots).

(There are many more models, but this is just a start.)

How should I structure the links between these nodes?

Method 1: Create separate tables, making use of foreign keys i.e.

```
Event_Timeslot (int event_id, int timeslot_id)
Timeslot_Session (int timeslot_id, int session_id)
Session_Person (int session_id, int person_id)
```

OR

Method 2: Create one table to describe all graph edges, but lose foreign key capability, i.e.

```
__EDGES__ (String type0, int id0, String type1, id1)
```

Which method is the "better" database design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a relational database like `mySQL` and per design practices specially in `many-to-many` relationship/cardinality a bridge table between two related `(many-to-many)` tables is the best design. Hence, **Method 1** for me is the best method/solution for this problem of yours.

However, if you are using `noSQL` type of database like `CouchDB` in which `Normalization` is not the way to go then your Method 2 would be suit the solution.